# My friend says my code is hard to read, I don't understand why

Tags: c

Ok so I was trying to solve this problem:

https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc11s2

and my solution is as follows:

```
#define in(ptr, i) while(i-->0){scanf(" %c", ptr++);} 
#define ans(ptr, i, n) while(i-->0){getchar(); (getchar()!=*(ptr++))?: n++;}
#define rst(ptr, r, i, n) ptr=r;i=n

int main(){

        int n, nCorrect = 0, i;
        scanf("%d", &n);    
        i = n;

        char r[n];
        char* ptr = r;

        in(ptr, i);     
        rst(ptr, r, i, n); 
        ans(ptr, i, nCorrect);

        printf("%d\n", nCorrect);

        return 0;
}
```

My friend keeps telling me I shouldn't write it like this. I was under the impression that using `#define` made it go first and so the program would run faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Ya, using macros here makes your code harder to read, and increases the chance that you'll create a weird order-of-operation bug. Just use normal functions. In the vast majority of cases, don't complicate your code with the goal of increasing efficiency until you've determined that there's actually a reason to do so.

Comment: Using `#define` like this does not make the program run faster

Comment: A reasonable compile would inline the function anyway so it probably isn't faster.

Comment: This is typical of programming contest participants who program in C or C++: They tend to macro all the things in search of that millisecond speed improvement. Your code doesn't look that bad, but for the love of all that is fluffy and nice, do not write this as actual code irl

Comment: Also, there isn't much need for the macros/functions here in the first place. Each is only encompassing a single loop in the worst case, and there's no indication that that code would be used in multiple places anyways. I love using excessive functions and even I think that this is taken too far.

Comment: `#define`'s literally get substituted into your code by the preprocessor. They are a way to improve readability, but you have used them to achieve the opposite effiect.

Comment: At least if you are going to use macros don't pass in parameters unless those bits change between invocations.  Once the preprocessor has its way the compiled code is identical to what would happen if you just put the code inline so there is no value unless you are trying toget rid of code duplication (which you aren't because you use each macro only once)

Comment: Asking a yes/no question about "hard to read" is like asking for a favorite color, it reveals little more than an opaque preference.  The *reason* it's hard to read is that it hides important control structure, and can produce unhappy surprises. Every one of your `#defines` is begging for incorrect code. What happens if somebody says `if (something) rst(blah,blah,blah);`  Seriously, look at what this will accomplish.

Comment: I have compiled the code.  With defines that take parameters: 70 assembly instructions.  With static file level functions: 68 instructions.  With defines that do NOT take parameters but use the variables from the lexical scope: 66 assembly instructions.  So speed isn't an issue.

Comment: What do you accomplish by calling getchar() and not assigning the result to a variable?  Are you trying to skip a space character?  You can't skip a newline like that because on Windows a newline is a carriage return/linefeed pair...  Also, you aren't checking scanf(), getchar() or printf() for errors.  And `(getchar()!=*(ptr++))?: n++;` could just be `n+=(getchar()==*(ptr++));`  which seems simpler to me and would be faster because there isn't a branch which could confuse the branch predictor.

Comment: All code with non-trivial macros is incredibly slow if you are measuring test and debug speed:(

Answer (score 11):

This is [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). `#define` does not "make things go faster", it inlines code, and *sometimes* inline code is the faster way of doing things.

Your variable names are utterly opaque, you're doing things like using a ternary for no real reason other than to look cool. This code is "minimal" as in maybe it works (there's no tests) and in terms of character count, but is otherwise **completely unmaintanable**.

I say this as someone who's written a lot of (sometimes deliberately) opaque Perl code: **DON'T**.

When writing code keep these points in mind:

- Declare **functions and variables** with *meaningful names*. Observe the *Principle of Least Surprise*, that is a function called `is_alive` should not format the hard drive, send an angry drunk email to your boss, etc., it should tell you if something's alive, and **that's it**. What does a function called `rst` do? It's a *surprise!*
- Do it the *standard way first*. Fight the tug of *Premature Optimization*. You call these functions *once* and even if you called them a million times, C on modern hardware is so ridiculously fast that you would be hard pressed to even benchmark how long this takes by hand with a stopwatch. It'd be instantaneous. **Don't optimize what you can't measure as being slow**.
- Macros need to be defined *carefully*, not just slapdash. They get *interpolated* which means different rules apply. `while(i-->0)` breaks completely if `i` is `x+2` for whatever reason. Learn how they work, then write them properly *if and when* you actually need a macro. **Be aware of syntax complications**.

Writing code that's simple yet effective, that's boring in that it contains no surprises, is not always easy, but it's always *necessary*. When you mature as a developer you'll write code that's increasingly boring, increasingly ordinary, because you'll be able to visualize simple solutions to complex problems in a way that avoids all the unnecessary fanfare and bravado of solutions like this.

All the fancy tricks here have saved *nothing*. When this code is compiled with optimizations the compiler will decide which functions to inline, and because there's IO involved, any time savings that *could* have resulted from the `#define` trickery are completely lost because of the amount of time the kernel will have to spend shunting data back and forth from kernel to userspace. Your changes will be significantly less than statistical noise.

If you want your program to be fast you need to know what sorts of things will make it slow. For example, `getch()` is actually really *slow* as each call requires a fairly painful excursion through the kernel. No amount of optimizing or macro magic can get around that. Instead, read it in all at once into a buffer and parse that using simple pointer comparisons:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  // Maximum size of file is:
  // + N to NNNNN (1-5 byte + newline = 6 bytes)
  // + 10,000 entries (letter + newline = 2 bytes each)
  // + Don't care about NUL terminator
  size_t max_size = 10000 * 2 + 6;
  char* raw = malloc(max_size);

  fread(raw, 1, max_size, stdin);

  char* p = raw;

  size_t count = atoi(p);
  while (*(p++) != '\n');

  int score = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    score += p[i * 2] == p[count * 2 + i * 2];
  }

  printf("%d\n", score);

  free(raw);

  return 0;
}
```

On Windows you'll need to adjust this to handle CRLF instead of just LF, but the same idea works.

`getch()` is brutal when reading lots of data. If you don't believe me, write a test program where you copy a large (~1GB) file using that approach, then compare to a more reasonable strategy of reading data in ~64KB chunks.

In a program where you're only reading a trivial amount of data, and 10K entries is inconsequential these days, the difference in performance here is academic, but the approach of dumping it into a buffer and manipulating it there saves a ton of fuss with decoding things that don't need to be decoded, stripping this problem down to the essentials: Comparing different parts of the string to other parts and counting the matches.

Comment: And even if you don't use a macro, but a function instead, this does not mean that the code *wont* be inlined. It merely doesn't force it to be. Generally it is a good idea to let the compiler do the optimization. *Sometimes* inlining function calls may be a pessimization as well.

Comment: @walnut The amount of wizardry a good optimizing compiler does when let off the leash is truly extraordinary. Things I would think would be slow take basically zero time. This gets even more ridiculous when you can vectorize something.

Comment: `atoi(p);` is suspicious as `p` does not certainly point to null character terminated data.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica This is only "competition" grade code, not production, and it terminates on the first LF character it finds, at least on my machine (clang).